# Symfony - DomCrawler get element by custom attribute

Tags: php, symfony, dom, domcrawler

I need filter this tag

```
<div dir=3D"ltr">
```

I tried it

```
$crawler = $crawler->filter('div[dir=3D"ltr"]');
```

But not work...

```
Expected "]", but <identifier "D" at 6> found.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `css-selector` uses XPath under the covers, and that's invalid XML so *I don't think* there's a way around that using `filter` or `filterXPath`. Other than fixing the markup. That *looks* like an encoding artifact, since `3D` decodes to `=`.

Comment: @msg It is the html generated by gmail...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to work with data that is [quoted-printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) encoded. You need to decode the data before treating it like HTML. PHP has the built-in function [`quoted_printable_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-decode.php) to do this for you.

```
$html = quoted_printable_decode($html);
$crawler = new Crawler($html);
$crawler = $crawler->filter('div[dir="ltr"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            $crawler->filter('div')->each(function (Crawler $node, $i) {
                if ($node->attr('dir') == '3D"ltr"') {
                    // It's the element
                }
            });
```

This is the best way I know of to do it. Not sure if it's the best but it will work.